# WPF and DirectX - Game Overlay

Tags: wpf, directx, overlay

Greetings

I've read WPF utilizes DirectX so I'm wondering if it is possible to create a Game Overlay with WPF. I have tried with Winforms or WPF by itself and the transparent forms or windows always cause problems for streaming software thus I'm wondering is it possible to do the following:
[image: sketch]

Create a WPF application which shows a Window on the desktop with all the options needed for the overlay. Once all the options is filled in you can press Update and the Overlay is created in the game with all the information on it. The WPF app itself won't be visible on the stream. This means all the viewers will not have any trouble with it when the broadcaster changes settings.

**More about the overlay**
The overlay will be a scoreboard so it will need a set amount of info. For example:
[image: rough sketch scoreboard]

**So to sum up my question(s)**

- Can I make a WPF application which
  dynamically creates a DirectX overlay
  ingame?
- Since it needs to work in DirectX9,
  is this project possible to make by a
  single dev (me) which has little to
  no exp with DirectX?
- If it is possible, where should I
  start?

Thanks in advance for all your possible insights and replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want would be possible using [D3DImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx). It allows you to host any Direct3D content within WPF and also allows you to have overlay with transparency. [Here is a simple example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656785.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, is it also possible to get this D3D Image directly into the running game? In this case it would be Starcraft II

Comment: No the hosting application must be a WPF application. It is possible to create a WPF window that has no border and is partly transparent. Maybe you could put that window on top of the SC2 window.

Comment: The problem is that the WPF window cannot be set to 'AllowsTransparency="True"', this stops the window from being shown on the stream. Even a partially transparent window is not shown.

Comment: This answer is precisely the *reverse* of what the questioner wants to do! Integrating WPF into DirectX apps is much harder.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment above, it sounds like your really trying to inject your overlay (at least from the user's perspective) into Starcraft II. You would almost have to host a copy of the directx buffer.
Also, besides WPF, you might want to look at XNA.