# Access the underlying DirectX surface/rendertarget of a rendered WPF page/window

Tags: c++, wpf, graphics, directx, unmanaged

I need to access the rendered raw pixels of a (managed) WPF page/window from unmanaged code.

The underlying (unmanaged) engine renders pixels both in cpu memory and in gpu memory (DirectX) before copying the final raster to an external device. The ideal would be to access raw pixel data from cpu memory or from a directx rendertarget or dxgi surface in gpu memory.

What i need is similar to [WPF and DirectX - Game Overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388492/wpf-and-directx-game-overlay) but the reply here is the opposite of the problem in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stumbled onto this info a few days ago - and here I find a question for that very topic! Here you go, [this](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/438/How-to-get-access-to-WPF-s-internal-Direct3D-guts.aspx) link should be what you need.