# Displaying WPF window ontop of directX game

Tags: c#, wpf

I know that this question was asked before but i dont know if its me or this question was not answered properly, maybe because im new to programming... anyways i'm creating this application where i'm suppose to display a WPF window over directX games, the window will display normal data like a list or something. can anyone help me by guiding or even posting the code?

Comment: Typically, you'd go the other direction: display a DX window / control inside of the WPF application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwapChainBackgroundPanel is a XAML element for developing full-screen, primarily DirectX-focused apps. Unlike SurfaceImageSource and VirtualSurfaceImageSource, SwapChainBackgroundPanel is a XAML element rather than an ImageSource; it inherits from the XAML Grid layout panel and enables apps to create and fully control a full-screen DirectX swap chain, on top of which all other XAML content is overlaid

[combining-xaml-and-directx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/03/15/combining-xaml-and-directx.aspx)

[Introducing-DirectX-to-WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/200908/Introducing-DirectX-to-WPF)

[wpf-and-directx-game-overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388492/wpf-and-directx-game-overlay)

Comment: thx alot for your guidance. however SwapChainBackgroundPanel  requires that the application is created using metro style not WPF. but the 3rd link is very helpfull. thx again:).

Comment: 2/3 links dont work.